# Java parallel threading

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Signal2NoiseRatio
{
    public ImagePlus SingleSNR(ImagePlus imagePlus) throws InterruptedException
    {

        new Thread()
        { 
          @Override public void run() 
          { 
              JFrame imageFrame = new JFrame("ROI");
              Container imageFrame_Container = imageFrame.getContentPane();
              IIImagePanel imagePanel = new IIImagePanel();
              imageFrame_Container.add(imagePanel);
              imagePanel.setImage(imagePlus.getImage());
              imagePanel.getDisplayedImage();
              imageFrame.setVisible(true);
              final SNRSingleImageListener sNRSingleListener = new SNRSingleImageListener(imagePanel);  
              imagePanel.addMouseListener(sNRSingleListener);
              imagePanel.addMouseMotionListener(sNRSingleListener);
          }
        }.start();


        new Thread() 
    { 
      @Override public void run() 
      { 

          for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i++)
          { 
             System.out.println("schleife "+i);
                     // ask if useractions are done ..
          }

          synchronized( Signal2NoiseRatio.this ) 
          { 

             Signal2NoiseRatio.this.notifyAll(); 

          }
      }
    }.start();


        synchronized (this) 
        {
        this.wait();
            // if userinteractions are done, go on
        }


        return imagePlusToProcess;
    }
}
```

The first `new Thread()` perform a frame which presents an image in it. My intention was to present the image in a new thread to wait for some user interactions on the image. But the code leads the frame to a white window and the image is not visible and the frame is not usable.

In the second thread I want ask in a short interval if the user actions are done.

It is not really a nice solution but it is be possible? what's wrong here?

Thank you stackoverflow!

Comment: You `IIImagePanel` class works without the threads?

Comment: One issue is that you cannot create or access Swing components from any thread other than the event dispatch thread.  Secondly, your `notifyAll()` call will never execute, as it is inside a `synchronized` block.  I believe for what you're looking for, neither of those `synchronized` blocks are necessary.

Comment: IIImagePanel works without the threads.

Comment: @Rob I: That's not correct. The corresponding call to `wait` will release the lock so `notify/notifyAll` can be called. It is by design.

Comment: @Tudor - thanks, of course you're right, I always get myself in trouble with the low-level sync methods.

Comment: Rob, above, is right about calling Swing components off the EventQueue.  Actually, you can create them and access them from other threads, and they even work--most of the time.  But the bugs you get are occasional, unrepeatable, and impossible to track down.  The only way to fix them is to say "Gee, to get bugs like that I must be calling Swing components off the EventQueue" and search your code line by line to find the problem(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The invoker of the method was an AWT-Thread. I created a new Thread for the invoker and so the AWT-Thread was not blocked and the then frame and image could present correctly.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few problems here:

1.If this

```
synchronized (this) 
{
    this.wait();
    // if userinteractions are done, go on
}
```

is happening on the UI thread, then you will block it from receiving user input (or doing anything else) until the object is signaled.

2.This part seems pretty much overcomplicated:

```
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i++) {
                System.out.println("schleife " + i);
                // ask if useractions are done ..
            }

            synchronized (Signal2NoiseRatio.this) {

                Signal2NoiseRatio.this.notifyAll();

            }
        }
    }.start();

    synchronized (this) {
        this.wait();
        // if userinteractions are done, go on
    }
```

Just use:

```
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i++) {
                System.out.println("schleife " + i);
                // ask if useractions are done ..
            }

        }
    }.start();

    t.join();
```

Unless you're signaling more than what you had above. But again, this is redundant, since starting a thread only to wait for it to finish does not make much sense...

Comment: What easier way can I implement to use a new Frame in the method SingleSNR?? I cannot make it run. My aim is to wait for the user interactions before the method returns.

Comment: @haxenmaxen: So you want something like a modal frame? So it appears but it you cannot access the parent frame until the child is closed?

Comment: hmm I think you get it partial. the method SingleSNR gets a image to process and should return the new processed image. therefore the user should select a rectangle on the image. the selected area will be calculated and processed. for the rectangle selection I need an new Frame with the image. The method should wait for the users selected rectangles and calculate something after. after all it should return the new image.

Comment: @haxenmaxen: AFAIK you don't really need a new thread for this. Just create the new frame object on the parent frame's thread and make it visible. It should work like this.